# Enable 'Basic' on visual studio hosted IIS authentication

Tags: wcf, iis, basic-authentication

I've created a 'WCF Service Application' in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8 and then set the .svc file as the default page.  When I hit F5 to debug, WCF Test Client tells me that `The authentication schemes configured on the host ('Anonymous') do not allow those configured on the binding 'BasicHttpBinding' ('Basic')`

I've gone into the control panel and for IIS enabled Basic on the authentication types, but that doesn't seem to be what's required.

Any pointers as to how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using IIS or IIS express for this?

Comment: I'm using IIS express

Answer (score 0):

Running with VS apparently uses IIS express.  To enable Basic authentication, just edit the file `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` and set the basicAuthentication enabled to true.